# The data types nvarchar and nvarchar are incompatible in the '&' operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, addition, nvarchar

Trying to add dosrorder.nummer to Dossier.nummer but unfortunately SQL tells me

The data types nvarchar and nvarchar are incompatible in the '&' operator.

```
SELECT     
    Dossier.OrderType, Dossier.Nummer AS OrderNummer, 
    DosrOrder.Nummer, Dossier.Nummer & [.] & DosrOrder.Nummer AS Totaal
FROM         
    Dossier 
INNER JOIN
    DosrOrder ON Dossier.ID = DosrOrder.DosrID
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong way to concatenate in SQL Server. The right way is using `+` (assuming your columns are `NVARCHAR`):

```
SELECT  D.OrderType, 
        D.Nummer AS OrderNummer, 
        DO.Nummer, 
        D.Nummer + N'.' + DO.Nummer AS Totaal
FROM Dossier AS D
INNER JOIN DosrOrder AS DO
    ON D.ID = DO.DosrID
```